# Linear combination of columns 2

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I check if a vector is a linear combination of a matrix?

For example:

Is $\begin{bmatrix}-6\\9\\7\\6\\1\\-4  \end{bmatrix}$ a linear combination of the columns of $\begin{bmatrix} 6&0&6&-2&4\\-9&0&-9&6&0\\-7&1&-7&0&-8\\-6&0&6&1&-6\\-1&4&-1&-7&-10\\4&-1&4&2&8  \end{bmatrix}$ ?

Comment: Append this column vector to the right of the matrix and calculate its RREF.  Row operations doesn't change linear independence.

Comment: In this situation, the given column vector is just the negative of the first column of the given matrix. But the above comment still stands. Another way is to see if there is a solution to $Ax=b$ where $A$ is the given matrix, $b$ is the given column vector. If there's a solution, it'll give you precisely the coefficients for the linear combination. There are many ways to think about this problem, so to give proper insight, it would help to know your background.

Comment: A vector (like this one) can't be "a linear combination of a matrix" (like this one) because they -- this vector and this matrix -- don't belong to the same vector space. This vector, however, may be a linear combination of the columns of this matrix, and I bet that's what you meant to ask.